# Dynamic Drop Down lists using ajax, sql and php

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a code which is working well. It populates the dropdowns dependent upon the previous list but there is a problem.
In the html form in the `<option value ="">` field it displays "id" which is a numeric value instead of "name". Can someone please tell me how it can display "name" instead of the value. The actual problem is that it when it saves data in the sql database, it stores the corresponding "id" of the country or the state or city rather than its "name".

This is the code that I am using. I have tried changing the last line in ajax.php `echo "<option value='$entity_id'>$enity_name</option>";` to `echo "<option value='$entity_name'>$enity_name</option>";` but then the dynamic dropdowns do not work as they are dependent upon "id". Many thanks for your help.

ajax.php

```
<?php
    /* File : ajax.php
     * Author : Manish Kumar Jangir
    */
    class AJAX {

        private $database = NULL;
        private $_query = NULL;
        private $_fields = array();
        public  $_index = NULL;
        const DB_HOST = "localhost";
        const DB_USER = "admin";
        const DB_PASSWORD = "admin";
        const DB_NAME = "disciples";


        public function __construct(){
            $this->db_connect();                    // Initiate Database connection
            $this->process_data();
        }

        /*
         *  Connect to database
        */
        private function db_connect(){
            $this->database = mysql_connect(self::DB_HOST,self::DB_USER,self::DB_PASSWORD);
            if($this->database){
                $db =  mysql_select_db(self::DB_NAME,$this->database);
            } else {
                echo mysql_error();die;
            }
        }

        private function process_data(){
            $this->_index = ($_REQUEST['index'])?$_REQUEST['index']:NULL;
            $id = ($_REQUEST['id'])?$_REQUEST['id']:NULL;
            switch($this->_index){
                case 'country':
                    $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM countries";
                    $this->_fields = array('id','country_name');
                    break;
                case 'state':
                    $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id=$id";
                    $this->_fields = array('id','state_name');
                    break;
                case 'city':
                    $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE state_id=$id";
                    $this->_fields = array('id','city_name');
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            $this->show_result();
        }

        public function show_result(){
            echo '<option value="">Select '.$this->_index.'</option>';
            $query = mysql_query($this->_query);
            while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $entity_id = $result[$this->_fields[0]];
                $enity_name = $result[$this->_fields[1]];
                echo "<option value='$entity_id'>$enity_name</option>";
            }
        }
    }

    $obj = new AJAX;

?>
```

index.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<head>
<title>Country State City Dependent Dropdown using Ajax</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_options('','country');
});

function load_options(id,index){
    $("#loading").show();
    if(index=="state"){
        $("#city").html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php?index="+index+"&id="+id,
        complete: function(){$("#loading").hide();},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#"+index).html(data);
        }
    })
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:800px; margin:auto;padding-top:100px;">
<h1>Country,State,City dynamic dependent dropdown using Ajax and Jquery</h1>
<form>
        <label>Select Country</label>
        <select id="country" name="country" onchange="load_options(this.value,'state');">
            <option value="">Select country</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label>Select State</label>
        <select id="state" name="state" onchange="load_options(this.value,'city');">
            <option value="">Select state</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label>Select city</label>
        <select id="city" name="city">
            <option value="">Select City</option>
        </select>
        <img src="loader.gif" id="loading" align="absmiddle" style="display:none;"/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem in storing the corresponding "id". You can get the name using that "id".

Comment: The form stores the data in a database where the name of the country is displayed as 1 or 2 or 3 etc rather than the name. Now from that database there are numerous queries which are run to produce search results which display country name, city name etc. That is where the problem arises. If the current script can store the name instead of the id, it will save a huge amount of work. many thanks.

Comment: When sending data to back-end script which stores the data to database, send the name of the country/state/city in ajax request itself. Can you post that script?

Comment: Thanks Sameer. The data is sent via the ajax.php script which is on the top of the page.

Comment: When sending data in url `url: "ajax.php?index="+index+"&id="+id,` you can send the `name` parameter as $('#'+index+' option:selected').text()

Comment: I changed the whole line `$("#"+index).html(data);` with the one you suggested but then it doesn't populate the first drop down menu on the index page. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks Sameer, I worked around a php solution for it and it is all sorted now. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the script to do what you want by

1. *showing* the id as a data attribute. --> `Ajax->show_result()`
2. using that attribute for the id parameter in the ajax call. --> `load_options()`
3. pass the whole <option> element to `load_options()`

---

`this.value` is wrong for the ajax query with the cahages blow because it is a name, but `this` still has the id as a data attribute.

```
<select id="country" name="country" 
        onchange="load_options(this, 'state');">
    <option value="">Select country</option>
</select>
```

since the id parameter is the option element from the form, we need to compensate to get the id correct.

```
function load_options(id,index){
...
that = $(id).find(":selected");
id = that.data('realid');

$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php?index="+index+"&id="+id,
...
```

let the value attribute hold name, but keep the id.

```
public function show_result(){
...
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        ...
        printf( '<option data-realid="%s" value="%s">%s</option>',
               $entity_id,
               $enity_name,
               $enity_name );
```

This should answer your question, and depending on how the form is submitted and stored, it may solve your problem. I doubt it however, because the part you neglected to show us is likely to expect an id for the state and city and not their names.

Answer (score 1):

My english is not good ,so i will just write some things i have got from you.

```
1: You want to get a dropdown list depend on the index
2: You want to shown selected options depend on the id
```

FirstLy , Your codes is terrible. The php codes just try to get the data you need, why did you mixed with html?

Let us try to solve the first proplem, get a dropdown list.
You should just let the php code to get the data you need, so you'd better modified your php function show_result, I would like to write like this:

```
public function show_result(){
        $tmpData = array();
        $i = 0;
        $query = mysql_query($this->_query);
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $id = $result[$this->_fields[0]];
            $enity_name = $result[$this->_fields[1]];
            $tmpData[$i]['id'] = $id;
            $tmpData[$i]['name'] = $enity_name;
        }
        return $tmpData;   //here it saves data which you want to shown in drop down list 
    }
```

then in the end of file ajax.php,

```
 $obj = new AJAX;
 echo json_encode($obj->show_result());
```

Then in the js script, try to parse the data which you get from ajax.php and it is a json string,
it contains the ids and names. produce the options of the dropdown selector here.

```
    function load_options(id,index){
    $("#loading").show();
    if(index=="state"){
        $("#city").html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php?index="+index,  //do not pass id 
        complete: function(){$("#loading").hide();},
        success: function(data) {
            var jsonObj = eval('('+data+')');
            var selected = false;
            var options = '';
            for(jsonObj in eachData){
             if(eachData.id == id)
               selected = true;  //  shown selected if it's the right option you want to see
             options +=  '<option                                                 value="'+eachData.id+'"'+selcted?"selected":""+'>'+eachData.name+'</option>';
             selected = false;
            }
            $("#"+index).html(options);
        }
    })
}
```

then you will get a drop down list as your wish. I just write these codes to guide you and i did not debug and test them , just try the ways: get data from php, shown them as html in page.

So that's all. And again sorry for my terrible english( I speak chinese well :) )