# Chained Select Boxes (Country, State, City)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a php page where I would like to select a location from a list of countries, states, and cities. The page contains other data for user signup (name, email, etc) so I don't want to refresh the page or anything when the select boxes refresh. Currently, each of the select boxes just load the full list of countries, states, or cities. I want them to be chained so I don't have duplicate city names (same name in different states or countries).

Locations are stored in a database, and are passed to the page on load. They are then looped through and added to the select box:

```
<tr>
    <label>Select State: </label>
    <select name="state" id="state_select" style="width:200px;">
        <option value="">Select a State or Province</option>
        <?php while($state = $states->fetchObject()) { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $state->id; ?>"><?php echo $state->title; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</tr>
```

Database structure is pretty simple:

```
Country : | id | title |
State : | id | title | country_id |
City : | id | title | state_id |
```

I can think of logic in an .onChange() statement that *should* clear the chained select box and append new options, but I am very new to web based languages and I can't get anything working. Below is my attempt, but I guess I can't reference between js and php easily. Note: I am aware that this snippet is really bad and contains errors. My thoughts were to have a script function that does the following:

1. Clear out all options in the State selection box (assuming you have changed the country selection)
2. Loop through the supplied list of states (SQL query passed by the controller)
3. Put a selection option in the State selection box for each entry that has a 'country_id' that matches the selected country_id

^ This would be fantastic if it is possible. Any other methods would be good too, but I have tried using ajax and JSON methods and I honestly don't understand them.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#country_select').change(function(){
            $('#state_select').empty();
            //for each state
            <?php while($state = $states->fetchObject()) {
                $temp = $('#country_select').val()); 
                //if country matches selected country 
                if($state->country_id == $temp){
                    // create an option ?>
                    var option = '<option value="">Test</option>';
                <?php// } 
                //then append that option?>
                 <?php// } ?>
             $('#state_select').append(option);
           });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: what is problem ur facing in that

Comment: what is the php loop inside the script tag supposed to be for? it makes no sense. php and javscript run in completely different environments and at different times

Comment: suggest looking into one of the numerous tutorials and/or jQuery plugins for this

Comment: Look at this example http://jdrop.no81no.com/html/examples/dropdowns/json-server.html

Comment: Won't be able to purchase the plugin unfortunately. Thanks though KA_lin
Also tried many tutorials with no luck already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756130/dynamic-drop-down-lists-using-ajax-sql-and-php for one example

Comment: http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-to-create-chained-select-with-php-and-jquery/ check this one

Comment: Was just reading that! Thanks though!

Comment: Why you have three tables? Since they have the same structure you should have only one; id(int), location(varchar), parent(int)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$('#mobile_phone_network option:selected').val()i didn't tested but it should work. It's simple and it will give you some idea

```
**HTML**
<div id="countryWrap"><select id="country" name="country"></select></div>
<div id="stateWrap"><select id="state" name="state"></select></div>
<div id="cityWrap"><select id="city" name="city"></select></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#country').change(function(){
    loadState($(this).find(':selected').val())
  })
  $('#state').change(function(){
    loadCity($(this).find(':selected').val())
  })


})

function loadCountry(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/ajax.php",
            data: "get=country"
            }).done(function( result ) {
                $(result).each(function(){
                    $("#country").append($('<option>', {
                        value: this.id,
                        text: this.name,
                    }));
                })
            });
}
function loadState(countryId){
        $("#state").children().remove()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/ajax.php",
            data: "get=state&countryId=" + countryId
            }).done(function( result ) {
                $(result).each(function(){
                    $("#state").append($('<option>', {
                        value: this.id,
                        text: this.name,
                    }));
                })
            });
}
function loadCity(stateId){
        $("#city").children().remove()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/ajax.php",
            data: "get=city&stateId=" + stateId
            }).done(function( result ) {
                $(result).each(function(){
                    $("#city").append($('<option>', {
                        value: this.id,
                        text: this.name,
                    }));
                })
            });
}

// init the countries
loadCountry();
</script>




**ajax.php** 

$countryId = isset($_POST['countryId'])  ? $_POST['countryId'] : 0;
$stateId = isset($_POST['stateId'])  ? $_POST['stateId'] : 0;
$command = isset($_POST['get'])  ? $_POST['get'] : "";

switch($command){
case "country":
$statement = "SELECT id, name FROM country";
break;
case "state":
$statement = "SELECT id, name FROM state WHERE country_id=".(int)countryId;
break;
case "city":
$statement = "SELECT id, name FROM country WHERE state_id=".(int)stateId;
break;
default:
break;
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare($statement);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();

echo json_encode($result);
exit();
```

Comment: It turns out that my coworker was using a script that broke my elements, so I managed to figure it out. This answer works well otherwise. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
           <!-- ****************For State Loads Starts***************************-->
           $("#field6").change(function (e){
           var state = 
           {
           '0': ['Not Available'],
           'Z1':['Australian Capital Territory','New South Wales',
           'Northern Territory','Queensland','South Australia',
           'Tasmania','Victoria','Western Australia'],
           'IN':['Delhi','Maharashtra','TamilNadu','Karnataka','Haryana',
           'Uttar Pradesh','Andhra Pradesh','Jammu and Kashmir',
           'West Bengal','Gujarat','Madhya Pradesh','Kerala',
           'Punjab','Bihar','Rajasthan','Orissa','Assam','NA',
           'Himachal Pradesh','Chhattisgarh'],
           'MY':['Johor','Kedah','Kelantan','Kuala Lumpur','Labuan','Melaka',
           'Negeri Sembilan','Pahang','Penang','Perak','Perlis','Sabah',
           'Sarawak','Selangor','Terengganu'],
           'CN':['Beijing','Anhui','Chongqing','Fujian','Gansu','Guangdong',
           'Guangxi','Guizhou','Hainan','Hebei','Heilongjiang','Henan',
           'Hubei','Hunan','Jiangsu','Jiangxi','Jilin','Liaoning','Nei',
           'Mongol','Ningxia','Qinghai','Shaanxi','Shandong',
           'Shanghai','Shanxi','Sichuan','Tianjin',
           'Xinjiang','Xizang','(Tibet)','Yunnan','Zhejiang']
           }    
           var value = this.value;
           // Access the object like city['CT'] .. That gives the Array
           state[value] !== undefined ? state[value] : '0';                                 
           var stateOptions = state[value];         
           var $field8 = $('#field8'),
           $field9 = $('#field9');  
           $field8.html(''); // clear the existing options  
           $field9.html(''); // clear the existing options                
           $.each(stateOptions, function (i, o) {
           $('<option>' + o + '</option>').appendTo('#field8');
           });// ------------>each end tag          
           });//----------------->on-change end tag
           <!-- ****************For State Loads Ended***************************-->
           <!-- ****************For City Loads Starts***************************-->
           $("#field8").change(function (e){     
           var city = 
           {
           '0': ['Not Available'],
           'TamilNadu' : ['Coimbatore','Mettupalyam','Karur','Pollachi'],
           'Karnataka' : ['Bangalore','Mysore','Bellary','Mandya','Chikmagalur'
           ,'Chamarajanagar','Udupi','Chikkaballapura'],
           'Delhi'     : ['Faridabad','Panchkula','Sonipat','Hisar','Palwal','Thanesar']         
           }
           var value = this.value;
           city[value] !== undefined ? city[value] : '0';
           var cityOptions = city[value];
           var $field9 = $('#field9');              
           $field9.html(''); // clear the existing options 
           $.each(cityOptions, function (j, k) {
           $('<option>' + k + '</option>').appendTo('#field9');
           });// ------------>each end tag
           });//----------------->on-change end tag
           <!-- ****************For City Loads Ended***************************-->
           }); //-------------------->ready end tag
           </script>


           HTML Tag :

           <div id="formElement6" class="sc-view form-design-field sc-static-layout sc-regular-size" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; padding: 6px 5px 9px 9px" >
           <div class="field-wrapper" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear: both" >
           <div class="_100" style="float: left; width: 96%; margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 2%" >
           <p style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" >
           <label for="Country" style="display: block; line-height: 150%; padding: 1px 0pt 3px; white-space: nowrap" >Country</label>
           <select id="field6" name="Country" style="width: 100%" >
           <option value="" selected="selected" >--Please Select--</option>
           <option value="YE" >Yemen</option>
           <option value="YT" >Mayotte</option>
           <option value="Z1" >Austria-SEAD</option>
           <option value="ZA" >South Africa</option>
           <option value="ZM" >Zambia</option>
           <option value="ZW" >Zimbabwe</option>
           <option value="ZY" >Taiwan(CO Only)</option>
           <option value="ZZ" >Others</option>
           <option value="AM" >Armenia</option>
           <option value="GB" >United Kingdom</option>
           <option value="SI" >Slovenia</option>
           <option value="LS" >Lesotho</option>
           <option value="MC" >Monaco</option>
           <option value="CU" >Cuba</option>
           <option value="SL" >Sierra Leone</option>
           <option value="FO" >Faroe Islands</option>
           <option value="GQ" >Equatorial Guin</option>
           <option value="IN" >India</option>
           <option value="KY" >Cayman Islands</option>
           <option value="ME" >Montenegro</option>
           <option value="MN" >Mongolia</option>
           <option value="AF" >Afghanistan</option>
           <option value="AZ" >Azerbaijan</option>
           <option value="BS" >Bahamas</option>
           <option value="CK" >Cook Islands</option>
           <option value="EC" >Ecuador</option>
           <option value="MY" >Malaysia</option>
           <option value="NZ" >New Zealand</option>
           <option value="QA" >Qatar</option>
           <option value="SJ" >Svalbard</option>
           <option value="IR" >Iran</option>
           <option value="KI" >Kiribati</option>
           <option value="LC" >St. Lucia</option>
           <option value="MD" >Moldova</option>
           <option value="BI" >Burundi</option>
           <option value="BW" >Botswana</option>
           <option value="CH" >Switzerland</option>
           <option value="CY" >Cyprus</option>
           <option value="PE" >Peru</option>
           <option value="PS" >Palestine</option>
           <option value="SA" >Saudi Arabia</option>
           <option value="SO" >Somalia</option>
           <option value="GY" >Guyana</option>
           <option value="KR" >South Korea</option>
           <option value="AO" >Angola</option>
           <option value="BZ" >Belize</option>
           <option value="MX" >Mexico</option>
           <option value="RU" >Russian Fed.</option>
           <option value="MR" >Mauretania</option>
           <option value="SH" >Saint Helena</option>
           <option value="FJ" >Fiji</option>
           <option value="FK" >Falkland Islnds</option>
           <option value="FM" >Micronesia</option>
           <option value="FR" >France</option>
           <option value="GA" >Gabon</option>
           <option value="GD" >Grenada</option>
           <option value="GE" >Georgia</option>
           <option value="GF" >French Guayana</option>
           <option value="GG" >GUERNSEY</option>
           <option value="GH" >Ghana</option>
           <option value="GI" >Gibraltar</option>
           <option value="GL" >Greenland</option>
           <option value="GM" >Gambia</option>
           <option value="GN" >Guinea</option>
           <option value="GP" >Guadeloupe</option>
           <option value="GR" >Greece</option>
           <option value="GS" >S. Sandwich Ins</option>
           <option value="GT" >Guatemala</option>
           <option value="GU" >Guam</option>
           <option value="GW" >Guinea-Bissau</option>
           <option value="HK" >Hong Kong</option>
           <option value="HM" >Heard/McDon.Isl</option>
           <option value="HN" >Honduras</option>
           <option value="HR" >Croatia</option>
           <option value="HT" >Haiti</option>
           <option value="HU" >Hungary</option>
           <option value="ID" >Indonesia</option>
           <option value="IE" >Ireland</option>
           <option value="IL" >Israel</option>
           <option value="IO" >Brit.Ind.Oc.Ter</option>
           <option value="IQ" >Iraq</option>
           <option value="IS" >Iceland</option>
           <option value="IT" >Italy</option>
           <option value="JE" >JERSEY</option>
           <option value="JM" >Jamaica</option>
           <option value="JO" >Jordan</option>
           <option value="JP" >Japan</option>
           <option value="KE" >Kenya</option>
           <option value="KG" >Kyrgyzstan</option>
           <option value="KH" >Cambodia</option>
           <option value="KM" >Comoros</option>
           <option value="KN" >St Kitts&amp;Nevis</option>
           <option value="KP" >North Korea</option>
           <option value="KW" >Kuwait</option>
           <option value="KZ" >Kazakhstan</option>
           <option value="LA" >Laos</option>
           <option value="LB" >Lebanon</option>
           <option value="LI" >Liechtenstein</option>
           <option value="LK" >Sri Lanka</option>
           <option value="LR" >Liberia</option>
           <option value="LT" >Lithuania</option>
           <option value="LU" >Luxembourg</option>
           <option value="LV" >Latvia</option>
           <option value="LY" >Libya</option>
           <option value="M4" >MIAMI</option>
           <option value="MA" >Morocco</option>
           <option value="MF" >SAINT MARTIN</option>
           <option value="MG" >Madagascar</option>
           <option value="MH" >Marshall Islnds</option>
           <option value="MK" >Macedonia</option>
           <option value="ML" >Mali</option>
           <option value="MM" >Myanmar</option>
           <option value="MO" >Macau</option>
           <option value="MP" >N.Mariana Islnd</option>
           <option value="MQ" >Martinique</option>
           <option value="MS" >Montserrat</option>
           <option value="MT" >Malta</option>
           <option value="AD" >Andorra</option>
           <option value="AE" >Utd.Arab Emir.</option>
           <option value="AG" >Antigua/Barbuda</option>
           <option value="AI" >Anguilla</option>
           <option value="AL" >Albania</option>
           <option value="AN" >Dutch Antilles</option>
           <option value="AQ" >Antarctica</option>
           <option value="AR" >Argentina</option>
           <option value="AS" >Samoa, America</option>
           <option value="AT" >Austria</option>
           <option value="AU" >Australia</option>
           <option value="AW" >Aruba</option>
           <option value="AX" >Åland</option>
           <option value="BA" >Bosnia-Herz.</option>
           <option value="BB" >Barbados</option>
           <option value="BD" >Bangladesh</option>
           <option value="BE" >Belgium</option>
           <option value="BF" >Burkina Faso</option>
           <option value="BG" >Bulgaria</option>
           <option value="BH" >Bahrain</option>
           <option value="BJ" >Benin</option>
           <option value="BL" >Blue</option>
           <option value="BM" >Bermuda</option>
           <option value="BN" >Brunei Daruss.</option>
           <option value="BO" >Bolivia</option>
           <option value="BR" >Brazil</option>
           <option value="BT" >Bhutan</option>
           <option value="BV" >Bouvet Islands</option>
           <option value="BY" >Belarus</option>
           <option value="C2" >Canary Island</option>
           <option value="C3" >CURACAO</option>
           <option value="CA" >Canada</option>
           <option value="CC" >Coconut Islands</option>
           <option value="CD" >Dem. Rep. Congo</option>
           <option value="CF" >CAR</option>
           <option value="CG" >Rep.of Congo</option>
           <option value="CI" >Cote d'Ivoire</option>
           <option value="CL" >Chile</option>
           <option value="CM" >Cameroon</option>
           <option value="CN" >China</option>
           <option value="CO" >Colombia</option>
           <option value="CR" >Costa Rica</option>
           <option value="CS" >Serbia/Monten.</option>
           <option value="CV" >Cape Verde</option>
           <option value="CX" >Christmas Islnd</option>
           <option value="CZ" >Czech Republic</option>
           <option value="DE" >Germany</option>
           <option value="DJ" >Djibouti</option>
           <option value="DK" >Denmark</option>
           <option value="DM" >Dominica</option>
           <option value="DO" >Dominican Rep.</option>
           <option value="DZ" >Algeria</option>
           <option value="EE" >Estonia</option>
           <option value="EG" >Egypt</option>
           <option value="EH" >West Sahara</option>
           <option value="ER" >Eritrea</option>
           <option value="ES" >Spain</option>
           <option value="ET" >Ethiopia</option>
           <option value="EU" >European Union</option>
           <option value="FI" >Finland</option>
           <option value="MU" >Mauritius</option>
           <option value="MV" >Maldives</option>
           <option value="MW" >Malawi</option>
           <option value="MZ" >Mozambique</option>
           <option value="NA" >Namibia</option>
           <option value="NC" >New Caledonia</option>
           <option value="NE" >Niger</option>
           <option value="NF" >Norfolk Islands</option>
           <option value="NG" >Nigeria</option>
           <option value="NI" >Nicaragua</option>
           <option value="NL" >Netherlands</option>
           <option value="NO" >Norway</option>
           <option value="NP" >Nepal</option>
           <option value="NR" >Nauru</option>
           <option value="NT" >NATO</option>
           <option value="NU" >Niue</option>
           <option value="OM" >Oman</option>
           <option value="OR" >Orange</option>
           <option value="PA" >Panama</option>
           <option value="PF" >Frenc.Polynesia</option>
           <option value="PG" >Pap. New Guinea</option>
           <option value="PH" >Philippines</option>
           <option value="PK" >Pakistan</option>
           <option value="PL" >Poland</option>
           <option value="PM" >St.Pier,Miquel.</option>
           <option value="PN" >Pitcairn Islnds</option>
           <option value="PR" >Puerto Rico</option>
           <option value="PT" >Portugal</option>
           <option value="PW" >Palau</option>
           <option value="PY" >Paraguay</option>
           <option value="RE" >Reunion</option>
           <option value="RO" >Romania</option>
           <option value="RS" >Serbia</option>
           <option value="RW" >Rwanda</option>
           <option value="S1" >SAIPAN</option>
           <option value="SB" >Solomon Islands</option>
           <option value="SC" >Seychelles</option>
           <option value="SD" >Sudan</option>
           <option value="SE" >Sweden</option>
           <option value="SG" >Singapore</option>
           <option value="SK" >Slovakia</option>
           <option value="SM" >San Marino</option>
           <option value="SN" >Senegal</option>
           <option value="SR" >Suriname</option>
           <option value="SS" >South Sudan</option>
           <option value="ST" >S.Tome,Principe</option>
           <option value="SV" >El Salvador</option>
           <option value="SY" >Syria</option>
           <option value="SZ" >Swaziland</option>
           <option value="T1" >TAHITI</option>
           <option value="TC" >Turksh Caicosin</option>
           <option value="TD" >Chad</option>
           <option value="TF" >French S.Territ</option>
           <option value="TG" >Togo</option>
           <option value="TH" >Thailand</option>
           <option value="TJ" >Tajikistan</option>
           <option value="TK" >Tokelau Islands</option>
           <option value="TL" >East Timor</option>
           <option value="TM" >Turkmenistan</option>
           <option value="TN" >Tunisia</option>
           <option value="TO" >Tonga</option>
           <option value="TP" >East Timor</option>
           <option value="TR" >Turkey</option>
           <option value="TT" >Trinidad,Tobago</option>
           <option value="TV" >Tuvalu</option>
           <option value="TW" >Taiwan</option>
           <option value="TZ" >Tanzania</option>
           <option value="UA" >Ukraine</option>
           <option value="UG" >Uganda</option>
           <option value="UM" >Minor Outl.Isl.</option>
           <option value="UN" >United Nations</option>
           <option value="US" >USA</option>
           <option value="UY" >Uruguay</option>
           <option value="UZ" >Uzbekistan</option>
           <option value="VA" >Vatican City</option>
           <option value="VC" >St. Vincent</option>
           <option value="VE" >Venezuela</option>
           <option value="VG" >Brit.Virgin Is.</option>
           <option value="VI" >Amer.Virgin Is.</option>
           <option value="VN" >Vietnam</option>
           <option value="VU" >Vanuatu</option>
           <option value="WF" >Wallis,Futuna</option>
           <option value="WS" >Samoa</option>
           <option value="XK" >Kosovo</option>
           </select>
           </p>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
           <div id="formElement7" class="sc-view form-design-field sc-static-layout sc-regular-size" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px" >
           <div class="field-wrapper" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear: both" >
           <div class="_100" style="float: left; width: 96%; margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 2%" >
           <p style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" >
           <input id="field7" type="hidden" name="DataSource" value=""  />
           </p>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
           <div id="formElement8" class="sc-view form-design-field sc-static-layout sc-regular-size" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; padding: 6px 5px 9px 9px" >
           <div class="field-wrapper" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear: both" >
           <div class="_100" style="float: left; width: 96%; margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 2%" >
           <p style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" >
           <label for="state" style="display: block; line-height: 150%; padding: 1px 0pt 3px; white-space: nowrap" >State</label>
           <select id="field8" name="state" style="width: 100%" >
           <option value="First" >First</option>
           <option value="Second" >Second</option>
           <option value="Third" >Third</option>
           </select>
           </p>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
           <div id="formElement9" class="sc-view form-design-field sc-static-layout sc-regular-size" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; padding: 6px 5px 9px 9px" >
           <div class="field-wrapper" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear: both" >
           <div class="_100" style="float: left; width: 96%; margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 2%" >
           <p style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" >
           <label for="city" style="display: block; line-height: 150%; padding: 1px 0pt 3px; white-space: nowrap" >City</label>
           <select id="field9" name="city" style="width: 100%" >
           <option value="First" >First</option>
           <option value="Second" >Second</option>
           <option value="Third" >Third</option>
           </select>
           </p>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: I insert this code on jsfiddle site, but I don't know what this code should do? Could you explain me?
http://jsfiddle.net/fj4y2rpx/