# how to filter options in dropdown list based on another drop down selection

Tags: php, mysql

I want to filter the options to display in the second dropdown list ('make') based on selected id from previous dropdown list ('type') instead of displaying all 'make' options.

How do I capture the id of type(first dropdown) in order to display list in make accordingly before the form is submitted?

here's the code:

```
mysql_select_db($database);
$query="SELECT * FROM car_make";
$result=  mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database);
$query_type="SELECT * FROM car_type";
$result_type=  mysql_query($query_type)or die(mysql_error());

<tr><td>Choose Car Type</td><td>:</td>//first dropdown (type)
      <td>
      <select name="type">
        <option value="">Please select a car Type</option>
                   <?php

        while($row_type=mysql_fetch_array($result_type))
                {
                     $carType=$row_type['carType'];
                     $carType_id=$row_type['carType_id'];                                       

        ?>                    
            <option value="<?php echo $carType_id; ?>"><?php echo $carType; ?></option>              

        <?php
        }
        ?>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Choose Car Make</td><td>:</td>//second dropdown (make)
      <td>
      <select name="make">
        <option value="">Please select a car make</option>
                   <?php         

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $carMake_id=$row['carMake_id'];
            $carMake=$row['carMake'];
        ?>


            <option value="<?php echo $carMake_id; ?>"><?php echo $carMake; ?></option>


        <?php
        }
        ?>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You can add an `onchange` event on `<select name="type">` and make an ajax call to load the items in 'make' dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for what's called a chained select.  Here's a php/ajax way to do it:

[Chained Select Boxes (Country, State, City)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579361/chained-select-boxes-country-state-city)