# Change a drop down list depending on first drop down list selection

Tags: php, jquery

I have 3 drop down lists, all get there values from an array. I would like to change the selection of the second and third drop down lists when the first box has changed.

i.e.

```
<select id="first_box">
  <option> options 1</option>
  <option> options 2</option>
  <option> options 3</option>
</select>

<select id="second_box">
  <option> options 1</option>
  <option> options 2</option>
  <option> options 3</option>
</select>

<select id="third_box">
  <option> options 1</option>
  <option> options 2</option>
  <option> options 3</option>
</select>
```

If you select option 3 in the first box, then change the second and third boxes to option 3

Here's the code I have so far

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#font-name').change(function($){
        alert('first box has been changed');
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

Sorry I should of mentioned that the 2nd and 3rd values would be different, I just used the option 1,2, 3 as an example. SORRY.

Here's my actual selection box code

```
<select id="font-name" name="layout_options[h1_font_name]">
    <?php foreach( $fonts as $key => $font ): ?>
        <option <?php if($key == $current) echo "SELECTED"; ?> value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $font['name']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

    <select id="font-font" name="layout_options[h1_font_font]">
    <?php foreach( $fonts as $key => $font ): ?>
        <option <?php if($key == $current) echo "SELECTED"; ?> value="<?php echo $font['font']; ?>"><?php echo $font['font']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

    <select id="font-css" name="layout_options[h1_font_css]">
    <?php foreach( $fonts as $key => $font ): ?>
        <option <?php if($key == $current) echo "SELECTED"; ?> value="<?php echo $font['css']; ?>"><?php echo $font['css']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Hey Dan, I am wondering what you ready need. Do you need to just change the value for second and third box, or create a whole new select box ? (second and third)

Comment: Hi John, I just need to change what's selected on the second and third boxes although I mentioned in your answer that the 2nd and 3rd option values are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use change event to select the current value and set to other one

```
$('#first_box').change(function(){
    $("select").not(this).val(this.value);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2u8cK/4/)

IF the drop down values are diff from other then You have to use index for current selected option

```
$('#first_box').change(function () {
    $("select").not(this).find('option:nth-child(' + ($(this).find('option:selected').index() + 1) + ')').prop('selected', true);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2u8cK/5/)

If you need only 2 drop down for knowing ID

```
$('#first_box').change(function () {
    $("#second_box,#third_box").find('option:nth-child(' + ($(this).find('option:selected').index() + 1) + ')').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: The second option works the best, I should of stated that my values were going to be different on the second and third boxes but your second example works. I do have 1 issue with it though, it seems to be changing other drop down menus on my page, I only want 2 to change

Comment: I updated for 2 dropdown only .. if you knew id you can use directly

Comment: Hi Bala, i've just updated the original post with my selection box code, this will give the id

Answer (score 3):

You will need to first add some values to your HTML, so you will have something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="first_box">
  <option value="">-- Please select a value --</option>
  <option value="option1">options 1</option>
  <option value="option2">options 2</option>
  <option value="option3">options 3</option>
</select>

<select id="second_box">
  <option value="">-- Please select a value --</option>
  <option value="option1">options 1</option>
  <option value="option2">options 2</option>
  <option value="option3">options 3</option>
</select>

<select id="third_box">
  <option value="">-- Please select a value --</option>
  <option value="option1">options 1</option>
  <option value="option2">options 2</option>
  <option value="option3">options 3</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#first_box').change(function () {
        var first_box_value = $(this).val();
        $('#second_box').val(first_box_value);
        $('#third_box').val(first_box_value);
    });
});
```

**JSfiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7q4ct/

Comment: If the text inside the option tag is as same as its value then we can ignore adding value attribute to it..

Comment: @Bala I agree with you. However is a good practice to have it. I am an "old fashion" web developer and I've seen many issues with the value for internet explorer 6 and 7, so just to make sure I am always advising people to have values at their options.

Comment: I should of stated that the 2nd and 3rd option boxes would have different values, Bala's 2nd example worked although it changed other drop down lists as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#first_box').change(function($){
    var SelectVal=$(this).val();
    $('#second_box,#third_box').val(SelectVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for what's called a chained select.  Here's a php/ajax version:

[Chained Select Boxes (Country, State, City)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579361/chained-select-boxes-country-state-city)

Answer (score 0):

you have to try something like below i.e try to append dynamically when ever you select ay item from firs drop down

```
$('#ddl1').change(function () {
    //empty lists 2 and 3
    $('#ddl2').html("");
    $('#ddl3').html("");

    var option_selected = $('option:selected', this).val();

    //populate ddl2
    $.each(data[option_selected]['Cities'], function (index, element) {
        $('#ddl2').append($('<option>', {
            value: element
        }).text(element));
    });

    //populate ddl3
    $.each(data[option_selected]['States'], function (index, element) {
        $('#ddl3').append($('<option>', {

            value: element
        }).text(element));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the [Cascading Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910281/jquery-dependent-drop-down-boxes-populate-how)
With example

```
    var drop2 = $("select[name=drop2] option"); // the collection of initial options
$("select[name=drop1]").change(function(){
    var drop1selected = parseInt(this.value); //get drop1 's selected value
    $("select[name=drop2]")
                     .html(drop2) //reset dropdown list
                     .find('option').filter(function(){
                        return parseInt(this.value) < drop1selected; //get all option with value < drop1's selected value
                      }).remove();  // remove
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HTEkw/
Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
     {
        $("#first_box").change(function()
              {
                  var sel = $(this).val();
                 $("#second_box").val(sel);
                  $("#third_box").val(sel);
              });                      
     });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eLtNG/

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#first_box').change(function($){
    if($('#first_box').val()=='option 3'){
        $('#second_box, #third_box').val('option 3');
    }
});
```