# Dynamically update select element options in JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a problem in populating dropdown lists.

I have a dropdown from which the user selects the **branch**, and a second dropdown that shows **related options**.

**HTML**

```
<select id="first-choice" onchange="leaveChange()">
    <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
    <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
    <option value="ECE">ECE</option>
    <option value="EEE">EEE</option>
    <option value="MECH">MECH</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="second-choice">
    <option>Please choose from above</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function leaveChange(){
    //what to insert here;
}
```

**PHP**

```
$branch=$_GET['branch'];
$username = "jaggu";
$password = "8374";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$selected = mysqli_select_db($dbhandle,"test") or die("Could not select examples");

$query = "SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE classid LIKE '%".$branch."%'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
    $query1="SELECT * FROM `examdup` WHERE `classid` LIKE '%".$branch."%'";
$result1= mysqli_query($dbhandle,$query1);  

while ($row1= mysqli_fetch_object($result1)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row1->month_year.'">'. $row1->title.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204934/how-to-populate-dependable-drop-down-using-ajax-and-php). You may also Google for `Ajax populate dropdown`

Comment: unable to get clear idea sir i am a beginner in this type of things thats why i posted two codes i down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the perfect answer to your question: [W3Schools AJAX PHP Database](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

And if you integrate this example into your code, it should look like this:

**HTML**

```
<select id="first-choice" onchange="leaveChange(this.value)">
    <option selected value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
    <option value="ECE">ECE</option>
    <option value="EEE">EEE</option>
    <option value="MECH">MECH</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="second-choice">
    <option>Please choose from above</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function leaveChange(branch){
        if (branch == "") {
            document.getElementById("second-choice").innerHTML = "<option>Please choose from above</option>";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("second-choice").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?branch="+branch,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
```

You should replace the name of file `test.php` to yours at this line:
`xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?branch="+branch,true);`