# Javascript into HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi I am trying to implement a HTML form. 
Let's suppose it has 4 fields- Name , Age , City (dropdown- contains A,B,C,D) and Region.
I want Region field to appear only when City selected is A or B and disappears if city is changed to C and D. Could anyone help with JS/Jquery code?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4v5mkfz9/):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>BEAT | Login</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favi.ico">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="login">
            <form>
                Name: <input type="text"></input>
                <br/>

                Age: <input type="text"></input>
                <br/>
                State: <select>
                          <option value="A">A</option>
                          <option value="B">B</option>
                          <option value="C">C</option>
                          <option value="D">D</option>
                        </select>
                        <br/>
                Region: <select>
                            <option value="north">North</option>
                            <option value="south">South</option>
                         </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about researching for more generic topics? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579361/chained-select-boxes-country-state-city. Also, here's some interesting reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem

Comment: Probably, you could hire someone to get your work done! :P
you would have asked some generic questions rather than going to the point!

Comment: You should have tagged the question for jquery and specified that you can use it, since you tagged it for javascript only, I had to code the answer in pure javascript.

Comment: @NikhilBatra Sorry I haven't tagged Jquery. Still I had mentioned JS/Jquery in the question. Anyways thank you for effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4v5mkfz9/4/)...

```
$('#region').css('display','none');
$('#state').on('change', function() {
    var state= $('#state').val();
    if(state=="A"||state=="B"){
        $('#region').css('display','block');
     }else{
         $('#region').css('display','none');
     }
});
```

Try this..

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't tagged it for jquery, so using pure javascript you should update the following:

In HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>BEAT | Login</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favi.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="login">
        <form>
            Name: <input type="text"></input>
            <br/>

            Age: <input type="text"></input>
            <br/>
            State: <select id="state">
                      <option value="A">A</option>
                      <option value="B">B</option>
                      <option value="C">C</option>
                      <option value="D">D</option>
                    </select>
                    <br/>
            <div id="region">
                Region: <select>
                        <option value="north">North</option>
                        <option value="south">South</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here I have added ids for `region` and `state` fields.

Updated the javascript to:

```
var state = document.getElementById("state");
state.addEventListener("change",function(){
var selected = state.options[state.selectedIndex].text;
    if(selected == 'A' || selected == 'B'){
        document.getElementById('region').style.display = 'block';    
    }   
    else{
        document.getElementById('region').style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Here the `state` element is bound to `change` event. On each change in the select list, the selected value is compared to 'A' and 'B'. If found equal, then `Region` field is displayed, else it is hidden.

See the updated fiddle: "http://jsfiddle.net/4v5mkfz9/6/"

Answer (score 1):

use in java script

```
$('#regionArea').hide();
$('#state').on('change', function() {
    var state= $('#state').val();
    if(state=="A"||state=="B"){
        $('#regionArea').show();
     }else{
         $('#regionArea').hide();
     }
});
```

and

```
<div id="login">
        <form>
            Name: <input type="text"></input>
            <br/>

            Age: <input type="text"></input>
            <br/>
            State: <select id="state">
                      <option value="A">A</option>
                      <option value="B">B</option>
                      <option value="C">C</option>
                      <option value="D">D</option>
                    </select>
                    <br/><div id="regionArea">
            Region: <select id="region">
                        <option value="north">North</option>
                        <option value="south">South</option>
            </select></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruderpartap/2ze36o4x/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>BEAT | Login</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favi.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="login">
        <form>
            Name: <input type="text"></input>
            <br/>

            Age: <input type="text"></input>
            <br/>
            State: <select id="state">
                      <option value="A">A</option>
                      <option value="B">B</option>
                      <option value="C">C</option>
                      <option value="D">D</option>
                    </select>
                    <br/>
            Region: <select id="Direction">
                        <option value="north">North</option>
                        <option value="south">South</option>
                     </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("state").addEventListener("change", CheckChange);

function CheckChange() {
 var state = document.getElementById("state");
 var selectedValue = state.options[state.selectedIndex].value;
 if(selectedValue == 'A' || selectedValue == 'B')
  {
     document.getElementById("Direction").style.visibility = "hidden";
   }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById("Direction").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
</script>
```

you can also use 
"document.getElementById("Direction").style.display"  To set Style Property...