# Filtering dropdown based on another dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have 2 separate dropdown lists. I need to get each dropdown to filter each other. Every example I have seen so far is an example for dropdowns that have the options hard-coded in. Mine uses a query to populate the options.

So how could I correctly have each dropdown menu filter each other?

Here is my HTML for the dropdowns on `index.php`:

```
<select id="collector" onchange="showUser(this.value)">             
    <option value="" selected disabled>Collector Name</option>
        <?php foreach($collect->fetchAll() as $name) { ?>
    <option class="<?php echo $name['Collector Name'];?>" value="<?php echo $name['Collector Name'];?>"><?php echo $name['Collector Name'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

<select id="date" onchange="showUser(this.value)">              
    <option value="" selected disabled>Bill Date</option>
        <?php foreach($bill_date->fetchAll() as $date) { ?>
    <option class="<?php echo $date['Date'];?>" value="<?php echo $date['Collector Name'];?>"><?php echo $date['Date'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Code that runs each time the dropdown is changed in `script` tags on `index.php`:

```
function showUser(str) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;

            var newTableObject = document.getElementById('billing_table');
            sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject);

        }
        }

    // ---- Gets value of collector dropdown selection -----
        var e = document.getElementById("collector").value;

        $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'index.php',
         data: e,
         success: function(response) {
             console.log(e);
         }
       });                  

    // ---- Gets value of the current selection in any of the dropdowns ----    
        xmlhttp.open("GET","dropdown-display.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        document.getElementById('billing_table').style.display = 'none';
    }

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var $select1 = $( '#collector' ),
        $select2 = $( '#date' ),
    $options = $select2.find( 'option' );

$select1.on( 'change', function() {
    $select2.html( $options.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
}).trigger( 'change' );


});
```

Query on my `index.php` page:

```
$collector = "SELECT [Collector Name]
  FROM [vSpecial_Billing]
  Group By [Collector Name]";

$billdate = "SELECT [Collector Name], [Date]
  FROM [vSpecial_Billing]
  Group By [Collector Name], [Date]";
```

I don't want to send the value to my `dropdown-display.php` page since my queries that populate the dropdowns are on my `index.php` page. However, if I put the value variable in the query, then it runs that query on load before a collector selection can be made and my bill date dropdown will then not be populated.

**EDIT:**

- I changed the `value` in the options for the date dropdown to Collector Name instead of Date
- I also added the `$(document).ready(function()` at the end of the middle block of code
- I updated the queries that I am using

It filters correctly now, however, on page load, the bill date is unable to selected. It is not populated with any rows. How can I change this?

Also, when I filter it, it defaults to the last date on the list. How can I get it to default to a hardcoded value such as "Date" and then the user can select from the filtered values?

Comment: I'd go a different route with this, by echoing a json object of both lists, with keys that filter one from another. That way you have the full lists ready to use dynamically on the page, instead of firing off an ajax to get new list content on each change. Well, this works if your lists and reasonable size ;)

Comment: OT: Also if you use jquery, go full jquery! Eliminates a lot of that old raw javascript and makes your code clearer.

Comment: @Randall my lists are pretty reasonable size...the collector dropdown has 9 entries and the date dropdown has about 40-50 entries

Comment: Ah, yeah, I'd stick with async pulls then. You will just need to isolate the list pulls from your normal population, so that they are not stepping over each other like you described there (missing info). Means a little bit of restructure!

Comment: @Randall Would you be able to show an example?

Comment: It would be a very involved example... a lot of work on my side (plus I'm buried in my own work haha). If no one else has chimed in later, I can take a stab for you. IN the meantime you could read over these options too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570904/use-jquery-to-change-a-second-select-list-based-on-the-first-select-list-option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579361/chained-select-boxes-country-state-city

Comment: @Randall I made some updates to my question below the EDIT. I went off one of those links you gave me. I think i am on the right track but still dont have everything working 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up a test case, using some example data, and made sure this works. Its a rough example, but I believe its doing what you need. With a lot less cruft in the works. I'm sorry, but I used full jquery, because I cannot be bothered to do long-hand javascript anymore haha (plus I couldn't really follow what you had going on in there).

There will need to be two files: `index.php` and `index-ajax.php` (for clarity)

index.php brief:

```
// note: these do not need to be in prepared statements (theres no variables inside)
$collect  = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT [Collector Name] FROM [vSpecial_Billing]");
$names    = $collect->fetchAll();
$billdate = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT [Date] FROM [vSpecial_Billing]");
$dates    = $billdate->fetchAll();
?>

<form id="testForm" action="">
    <select id="collector">             
        <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Collector Name</option>
        <?php foreach($names as $name) { ?>
            <option class="choice" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name['Collector Name']);?>"><?php echo $name['Collector Name'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <select id="date">              
        <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Bill Date</option>
        <?php foreach($dates as $date) { ?>
            <option class="choice" value="<?php echo $date['Date'];?>"><?php echo $date['Date'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="clearchoices" name="clearchoices" value="Clear Choices" />
</form>
```

Some things to note in the above:

- You only need to select by DISTINCT. No need to do GROUP BY to get all unique names, or all unique dates.
- I put the results of fetchAll into variables, out of habit, but you can move them into the foreach if you wish.
- I removed the `class` defines you had, because a class with spaces in it (in the case of a Collector Name) can be buggy.
- The Clear Choices button is just an example of how to reset those selects after they get filtered and filtered beyond what you can select.

This is the javascript portion (it goes in index.php before or after your form, or in the head):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#collector").change(function(e){
        $.post('index-ajax.php',{filter:'Name',by:$(this).val()},function(data){
            $("#date .choice").hide();
            $.each(data, function(key,row) {
       //       $("#date option[value='"+ row.item +"']").show();
                $("#date option").filter(function(i){
                    return $(this).attr("value").indexOf( row.item ) != -1;
                }).show();
            });
        },"JSON");
    });
    $("#date").change(function(e){
        $.post('index-ajax.php',{filter:'Date',by:$(this).val()},function(data){
            $("#collector .choice").hide();
            $.each(data, function(key,row) {
        //      $("#collector option[value='"+ row.item +"']").show();
                $("#collector option").filter(function(i){
                    return $(this).attr("value").indexOf( row.item ) != -1;
                }).show();
            });
        },"JSON");
    });
    $("#clearchoices").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();
        $("#collector .choice").show(); $("#collector").val('');
        $("#date .choice").show(); $("#date").val('');
    });

});
</script>
```

That block needs a lot of explaining, because I took all your long-hand javascript and packed it into jquery.

- Each select has its own handler event for when it changes.
- Each select does its own post ajax, with a different variable define to filter on.
- After the ajax returns, it hides all options in the OTHER select. Then enables all options which are returned by the json data of the ajax call. This could be handled differently, but I wanted to present one way of doing it.
- A key thing is setting `"JSON"` for the return handler of the `.post()` methods. You'll see why in `index-ajax.php`.

And now the index-ajax.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['filter']) and isset($_POST['by'])) {// sanity check

    $results = array();

    if (!empty($_POST['by'])) {
        // these _DO_ need to be in prepared statements!!!
        if ($_POST['filter'] == 'Name') { $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [Date] as item FROM [vSpecial_Billing] WHERE [Collector Name] = ?"; }
        if ($_POST['filter'] == 'Date') { $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [Collector Name] as item FROM [vSpecial_Billing] WHERE [Date] = ?"; }
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($_POST['by']));
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { $results[] = $row; }
    }

    echo json_encode( $results );
    exit;
}
```

This bit of code is actually pretty straightforward. All it does is determine which filter operation to do, prepares the sql, and then grabs distinct matching rows for output. The key thing though is it outputs as json, so the javascript that called this can handle the data easier!

Now... I had built all this in a test script, and my server hates "fetchAll", so your milage may vary on some of the DB code. I also left out all other form code and db setup handlers and all that. Figuring you have a handle on that.

I hope this helps you out, in some way or other.

**EDIT 11/7**

I made a slight change because I didn't realize the Collector Names in your db would have characters that would break all of this, oops. Two changes for odd character handling:

- The `select` for `collector` has its `option` values wrapped in `htmlspecialchars()`.
- The `jquery` portion for where each `select` `.change` event filters, is now filtering by looking for a matching index, using the `row.item` as a direct variable. Before, it was using it in a `value=' row.item '` match, which if the `row.item` had single quotes (or other bad chars), it would break the whole js event and fail!

Generally when I setup things like this, I use ID's and unique element id tags. That way I am only ever referencing by numbers, and wont run into odd character mash. An example of switching everything to ID's would be involved, and I think you have the gist of whats going on now.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So I implemented all of your code. I substituted your jquery for my `showUser` function and also created an `index-ajax.php` page and added my DB connection to it and substituted that text (`index-ajax.php`) in for `xtest.php`. When I select something from the dropdown, it says I have an internal server error. After checking the logs, this is what it says...`Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param()` which would be this line of code `$stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['by']);`. Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: Oops, looks like I had some leak from my test script setup on my end. As for the error... it looks like you are using PDO! I did not know this, and thus my example DB actions are using mysqli object oriented. You can change out the db stuff to match your PDO functions. I can edit my answer, but give me a bit to dig up the PDO versions of everything.

Comment: Ok, updated that bit on the prepare part. PDO allows it in the `execute()` method. Also adjusted the while loop, to use ASSOC since if it includes column indexes, it makes the jquery block a bit wonky ;)

Comment: Alright, that definitely fixed most of it....based on the selection that I make, I can see in my logs that it is pulling the correct data....but still when I make a selection, the other dropdown is blank so it isnt pulling the values into the dropdown quite yet

Comment: I'm not sure what alterations you may have made. Both were pre-filled with content when I was test building this. So, you may have re-introduced the original bug? =D

Comment: When I load the page, both dropdowns are pre-filled and look fine. However, when I select from either of the dropdowns, the other becomes blank with no selections available. However, if I inspect the page and go into my network tab and click the `index-ajax.php` page, I can see all of the selections that should populate the dropdown. They just arent getting put into the dropdown properly. Seems like it would be the `row.item` in the jquery. Should that be different in order to pull in the values correctly?

Comment: I havent made any alterations other than what you have given me

Comment: I realized the issue now. Your collector names must have characters in them which can cause escaping failures. I have updated the answer, and added a note to the bottom of it 11/7 showing what I changed. Sorry about that. I usually deal with ID's only for this sort of thing, and filtering by an actual name can cause those bugs to rise ;)

Comment: Hmm the values still dont seem to be populating the dropdowns....again, i can see them in the network tab but they just arent being brought in...i made the changes that you said

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158436/discussion-between-randall-and-rataiczak24).