# Link to filter three list select Ajax Php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, filter

I'm trying to link three html selects filtering my database tables:
here are the tables:

```
**Product:  id | id_typed | product_name;
type: id | product_name;
msn: id | msn_name;
prod_msn : id_prod | id_msn**
```

Every type has many products, every product is a part of one or many msn 
I want to link three html selects to filter the products when I select a type, and filter the msn when I select the product.

my html:

```
<html>
<div id="typeDiv"><select id="type" name="type"></select></div>
    <div id="productDiv"><select id="prod" name="prod"></select></div>
    <div id="msnDiv"><select id="msn" name="msn"></select></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#type').change(function(){
                loadProduct($(this).find(':selected').val())
            })
            $('#product').change(function(){
                loadMSN($(this).find(':selected').val())
            })


        })

        function loadType(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/ajax.php",
            data: "get=type"
            }).done(function( result ) {
                $(result).each(function(){
                    $("#type").append($('<option>', {
                        value: this.id,
                        text: this.type_name,
                    }));
                })
            });
        }

        function loadProduct(typeID){
        $("#prod").children().remove()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/ajax.php",  
            data: "get=productID&typeId=" + typeID
            }).done(function( result ) {
                $(result).each(function(){
                    $("#state").append($('<option>', {
                        value: this.id,
                        text: this.product_name,
                    }));
                })
            });
        }

        function loadMSN(productID){
        $("#msn").children().remove()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/ajax.php",
            data: "get=MSN&product=" + productID
            }).done(function( result ) {
                $(result).each(function(){
                    $("#msn").append($('<option>', {
                        value: this.id,
                        text: this.name,
                    }));
                })
            });
        }

    loadType();
    </script>
</html>
```

For the file Ajax.php:

```
<?php 
$typeID = isset($_POST['typeID'])  ? $_POST['typeID'] : 0;
$productID = isset($_POST['productID'])  ? $_POST['productID'] : 0;
$command = isset($_POST['get'])  ? $_POST['get'] : "";

switch($command){
    case "type":
    $statement = "SELECT id, type_name FROM type";
    break;
    case "prod":
    $statement = "SELECT id, product_name FROM product WHERE id_type=".(int)typeID;
    break;
    case "msn":
    $statement = "select m.MSN_NAME
    from msn m, PROD_MSN pm
    where pm.id_msn = m.ID
    and pm.id_prod =".(int)productID;
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($statement);
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();

    echo json_encode($result);
    exit();

?>
```

I'm not getting any results, I tried many tutorials and the code I applied was taken from [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579361/chained-select-boxes-country-state-city)

If you have any idea where the problem is coming from, it will help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Error messages? Have you looked at the PHP Error log? The  Apache error log? The browsers debugger? Any error logs

Comment: @RiggsFolly  $(document).ready(function(){
$ is not defined

Comment: You have not included jQuery library in your page!! @Devweb

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax code change

```
data: "get=productID&typeId=" + typeID
```

To

```
data: "get=prod&typeId=" + typeID
```

And change

```
 data: "get=MSN&product=" + productID
```

To

```
 data: "get=msn&product=" + productID
```

In switch case you are using `msn` and `prod` but in data you are sending `productID` and `MSN`!!

In your PHP code replace this

```
case "type":
    $statement = "SELECT id, type_name FROM type";
    break;
    case "prod":
    $statement = "SELECT id, product_name FROM product WHERE id_type=".(int)typeID;
    break;
    case "msn":
    $statement = "select m.MSN_NAME
    from msn m, PROD_MSN pm
    where pm.id_msn = m.ID
    and pm.id_prod =".(int)productID;
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
```

With this

```
case "type":
    $statement = "SELECT id, type_name FROM type";
    break;
    case "prod":
    $statement = "SELECT id, product_name FROM product WHERE id_type=".(int)$typeID;
    break;
    case "msn":
    $statement = "select m.MSN_NAME
    from msn m, PROD_MSN pm
    where pm.id_msn = m.ID
    and pm.id_prod =".(int)$productID;
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
```

You forgot $ in your query.

Comment: still nothing, I  don't even get the list without the filter (type list)

Comment: In your php code try printing the result. Check if you are getting a result from query? @Devweb

Comment: yes the query returns a result if I use it like this:
<select name ="type">
                <?php
                    $query = "Select * from type";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                    if ($result <> null){
                        while ($lign = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        $type = utf8_encode($lign[TYPE_NAME]);
                        $id = utf8_encode($lign[ID]);
                        echo("<option name='type[]' value='" . $id . "'> ". $type ."</option>");
                    }
                    }
  ?>

Comment: You have not included jQuery library in your file. @Devweb

Comment: I've added it, but still have an internal server error 500